# Best way to configure Reactstrap carousel images to be responsive

Tags: css, image, reactjs, responsive-design, reactstrap

I have done a lot of looking but there is suprisingly little documentation in regard to reactstrap carousel image responsiveness.

My ReactStrap carousel resizes responsively but the images do not.

Options I have researched/tried:

1. CSS via className in the carousel component itself? This is the one I thought might be best, but I haven't found a combination of background-size, height, and max-width that resizes the image properly.
2. srcset ? I'm not sure how to implement this or any other inline attribute, given that the carousel is a component
3. Perhaps some place in the carousel component itself?
4. Or is there a better way for me to modify the images?
5. Or is @media the answer via css?

`

```
const items = [
  {
    src: 'img1.png',
    altText: '',
    caption: ''
  },
  {
    src: 'img2.png',
    altText: '',
    caption: 'Freedom Isn\'t Free'
  },
  {
    src: 'img3.png',
    altText: '',
    caption: ''
  }
];

class HomeCarousel extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { activeIndex: 0 };
    this.next = this.next.bind(this);
    this.previous = this.previous.bind(this);
    this.goToIndex = this.goToIndex.bind(this);
    this.onExiting = this.onExiting.bind(this);
    this.onExited = this.onExited.bind(this);
  }

  onExiting() {
    this.animating = true;
  }

  onExited() {
    this.animating = false;
  }

  next() {
    if (this.animating) return;
    const nextIndex = this.state.activeIndex === items.length - 1 ? 0 : this.state.activeIndex + 1;
    this.setState({ activeIndex: nextIndex });
  }

  previous() {
    if (this.animating) return;
    const nextIndex = this.state.activeIndex === 0 ? items.length - 1 : this.state.activeIndex - 1;
    this.setState({ activeIndex: nextIndex });
  }

  goToIndex(newIndex) {
    if (this.animating) return;
    this.setState({ activeIndex: newIndex });
  }

  render() {
    const { activeIndex } = this.state;

    const slides = items.map((item) => {
      return (
        <CarouselItem
          className="carouselImg"
          onExiting={this.onExiting}
          onExited={this.onExited}
          key={item.src}
        >
          <img src={item.src} alt={item.altText} />
          <CarouselCaption captionText={item.caption} captionHeader={item.caption} />
        </CarouselItem>
      );
    });

    return (
      <Carousel
        activeIndex={activeIndex}
        next={this.next}
        previous={this.previous}
      >
        <CarouselIndicators items={items} activeIndex={activeIndex} onClickHandler={this.goToIndex} />
        {slides}
        <CarouselControl direction="prev" directionText="Previous" onClickHandler={this.previous} />
        <CarouselControl direction="next" directionText="Next" onClickHandler={this.next} />
      </Carousel>
    );
  }
}


export default HomeCarousel;
```

`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
.carousel-item > img { 
  width: 100%; 
}
```

... will fix your problem.
And it has nothing to do with Reactstrap. That's probably why you didn't find much. Has to do with the TwBs Carousel alone. I personally don't see any reason why that rule is not part of TwBs carousel CSS, because everyone expects that `<img>` to have a width of `100%` of its parent.

If you want to limit it to a particular carousel, modify the selector accordingly.

---

Another frequently requested TwBs carousel mod is:

```
.carousel-control-prev,.carousel-control-next {
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: This is the answer. Kicking myself for not seeing the forest for the trees. And thank you also for the other TwBs carousel mod. It is nice to have the cursor turn active when hovering over the arrows.

Answer (score 6):

Good day and Hello,

I already tried this reactstrap with the Carousel component in my reactjs app.
I solved this by adding bootstrap 4 classess "d-block w-100".

I created this in my reactstrap Carousel component and in this element

from this:

```
<img src={item.src} alt={item.altText} />
```

I changed to:

```
<img className="d-block w-100" src={item.src} alt={item.altText} />
```

I just copied these classes (d-block w-100) from bootstrap 4 documentation
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/

This is my example that I used Reactstrap Carousel with Dynamic data from my WordPress Rest API data.
https://github.com/jun20/React-JS-and-WP-Rest-API/tree/home-carousel-final

Answer (score 1):

Given bootstrap uses flexbox, you can make the reactstrap carousel images responsive by adding this to your css:

```
.carousel-item, .carousel-item.active {
    align-items:center;
}
```

This seems to prevent the image height from stretching. Worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the reactstrap Carousel example 1 on this page https://reactstrap.github.io/components/carousel/

Here's how I got it to be responsive in my use case:

```
        <CarouselItem
          onExiting={() => setAnimating(true)}
          onExited={() => setAnimating(false)}
          key={item.src}
        >
          <img src={item.src} alt={item.altText} style={{ width: "100%"}}/>
          <CarouselCaption captionText={item.caption} captionHeader={item.caption} />
        </CarouselItem>
```

So, passing in `style={{ width: "100%"}}` to the `img` tag, made my oversized images fit the screen perfectly and may work for others coming here.